# Delete all data in Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

is there a way to delete all data from a specific worksheet by setting a condition when it should be deleted? I want to keep the 1st row of my Excel sheet and delete all data each year on January the 1st.

Comment: You could just create a new sheet, copy the first row to the new sheet, delete the old sheet and rename the new sheet

Comment: Why not have a template sheet with all the headings ready then just make a copy and rename?

Comment: You want a macro to just delete rows ONCE per year? To be honest, I do not think it's worth at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the next approach, please. You **must start the workbook in discussion some days before the date when you need it to clear the sheet** and let it open. Its `Workbook_Open` event will call the `Sub` doing the job:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime "07:00:00", "DeleteAllExcepFirstRow"
End Sub
```

It will run every day at 07:00:00 (being recursively called_, but it will process the sheet only on first of January, when **the workbook must be open**...

The `Sub` doing the clearing job:

```
Sub DeleteAllExcepFirstRow()
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
 If Date = DateSerial(2021, 1, 1) Then
    sh.Range(sh.cells(2, 1), sh.cells(Rows.count, Columns.count)).Clear
    Exit Sub 'it does not call itself, anymore
 End If
 Application.OnTime "07:00:00", "DeleteAllExcepFirstRow"
End Sub
```

Comment: I think condition is also part of OP's problem.

Comment: @FaneDuru: Ask OP about details of the question first. Don't answer if the question is not clear (even if you miss the opportunity to gain some reputation).

Comment: @ali srn: You were right! I wasn't careful enough when I read the question. Sorry...

Comment: @FunThomas:  You were right! I wasn't careful enough when I read the question. But not because of the reputation issue. Sorry... I will try adapting the answer in order to touch both aspects.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your answers, sorry for the late reply but I had to check all the codes to see if I get what I want, the one suggested by @FaneDuru works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It should be done easily with a little macro, do it by hand with the recorder and just add the condition with the date.

For the date you can store the date of the last openning in a sheet (Ex : 12/12/2020) so if you open it the 2nd january you can check if the 1st january is past.

To delete :

```
Rows("2:1048576").ClearContents
```

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a comment. If you lack the reputation to make a comment, then please earn that reputation first.

Comment: Ok I'll try... However this is an answer, not totally coded but one solution is here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    
    If Month(Date) = 1 And Day(Date) = 1 Then
    
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Rows("2:" & .Rows.Count).Clear
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: if sheet is not opened on 1st of January (because of new years eve hangover...), code will never executed. If, however, sheet is opened more than once on 1st of January, data already entered will get lost...